Is there a way to configure environment variable at runtime?
Is there a way to build artifacts once and propagate them through different environments but still enabling them to read environment variables from the machine they are being deployed to?
So, for example, we have a build pipeline and after we get artifacts we deploy them to 3 environments: dev, qa, prod.
Is there a way that artifacts deployed to dev somehow know they are on dev, those on qa that they are on qa and prod that they are on prod without having a separate build for each environment?
I understand angular runs on the client machine so this would have implications on hosting solution as well. I am just wondering if there is some way of injecting some kind of a variable, like CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT into chunks or main.ts or even index.html at runtime or actually, at the moment of serving the application?

As specified in this answer, you could pass variable to your Angular root component using an html attribute, I guess you could use the web server serving your app to inject the environment variable inside your index.html.
To solve this, I would put a value to be substituted inside a custom html attribute (I usually encapsulate this kind of string between doubles % signs but thats just a habit of mine and not necessarily the way to go)
Consider the following code snippet :
index.html
<app-root envAttribute="%%ENV%%">
    <div>Loading...</div>
</app-root>

With  this, you could replace the placeholder with a variable defining the environment on which the application is running, you can achieve this using sub_filter if your web server is nginx, or mod_substitute in Apache (those are the only two I'm familiar with, so you might have to search for a more specific solution if you're not using one of these.)
nginx
location / {
    sub_filter '%%ENV%%' dev;
}

Apache
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
    <Files "index.html">
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
        # Replace %%ENV%% with dev, n = full string match, no regex, i = case insensitive
        Substitute "s/%%ENV%%/dev/ni"
    </Files>
</IfModule>

(Note that mod_substitute is only available since Apache version 2.2.7)
Then you only need to recover the value of the custom attribute inside the app.component once the application is boostrapped :
app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        const env = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('envAttribute');
    }
}

Hope this helps !
